# Android not opening camera using zxing

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, zxing

I'm trying to make the basic ZXing functionality to scan qr codes using their  [basic instructions](https://demonuts.com/scan-barcode-qrcode-kotlin/?fbclid=IwAR1aR0D-b9GqpVpDjsz_UT4EQIYjuDttuYr2gF0WvlHz3dh54t4YESjHZo0), but my camera does not open it just goes to the blank ScanActivity.

---

I've already added the "implementation" on module app dependency

`implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'`

and permission on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

I've also manually allowed its permission on the settings of the android phone i'm testing it on

---

My main activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        tvResult = tvresult

        btn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, ScanActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    companion object {

        var tvResult: TextView? = null
    }
}
```

ScanActivity Class

```
class ScanActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private var mScannerView: ZXingScannerView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mScannerView = ZXingScannerView(this)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan)

        mScannerView!!.setResultHandler(this) // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
    }

    public override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mScannerView!!.setResultHandler(this) // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
        mScannerView!!.startCamera()          // Start camera on resume

    }

    public override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mScannerView!!.stopCamera()           // Stop camera on pause
    }

    override fun handleResult(rawResult: Result) {
        // Do something with the result here
        // Log.v("tag", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
        // Log.v("tag", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)

        MainActivity.tvResult!!.setText(rawResult.text)
        onBackPressed()

        // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
        //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }}
```

[image: Main Activity]
[image]

after i click on the Scan barcode button it just goes to this
(im expecting the camera will open because of the `startCamera()`

Comment: you call `startCamera()` twice, is that ok? i.e. once in onCreate once in onResume

Comment: removed*, sorry i've updated the code, i was just trying to see if i could force it to open on onCreate.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, it was permission related.
Try adding the following within the onCreate(..)

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@MainActivity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), 123)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, by the way if someone else has this problem, you forgot to add mScannerView in your Layout